# Securing Password Management in TSQLite3Connection with SQLCipher

Tags: lazarus, sqlcipher

I am working on an application in Lazarus with a SQLCipher database. I use the TSQLite3Connection component for connection. Secure password management is crucial to me, especially when using SQLCipher. I want to understand how TSQLite3Connection handles the password, particularly in terms of:

1. Password Storage: How securely is it stored in TSQLite3Connection? Is it encrypted in memory?
2. Password Lifecycle: How long does the password remain in memory after connecting to the SQLCipher database? Can its removal be managed?
3. Protection Against Debuggers: How to secure the password from being read by debuggers?
4. Additionally, the password is provided to TSQLite3Connection upon request. How can this process be secured?

My aim is to ensure that the SQLCipher password is securely managed, minimizing the risk of exposure, including from debuggers.

Thank you for your advice and tips.

I haven't looked for a solution yet.